# $.mobile.changePage cannot jump to another page in phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

When I use PhoneGap and the jmq development app, `$.mobile.changePage` cannot change to another page, code snippets are as follows：

```
$('#travel_img').bind("click", function () {
  $(this).attr("src", "img/travel_highlight.png");
  $.mobile.changePage("views/main.html", "slide", false, true);
});
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `.on` instead of `.bind`

Comment: Which mobile platform? Any error output?

Comment: Thanks, I have figure out for the issue !

Comment: @ranfi.ren You should post then the answer for your own question, for others to learn :-)